# What's the reason behind decorations such as [ResponseType(typeof(void))] in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I was reading that one reason is to give the online help clues about the return type. As I don't use the WebAPI help features I am wondering:

Is there any other reason why I should decorate my controller methods with information on the response types such as:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
```

or:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Question))]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not into help, there is no other reason. `ApiExplorer` is the class that is interested in this attribute. If you just search for `ResponseType` in Web API source, you will see that all occurrences are related to help.